# How to check whether a string is only null without using (string== null)?

Tags: java, sonarqube

If I use the `if(string==null)` it will become a sonar violation. However sonar suggestion is `StringUtils.isEmpty(string)`. But it will also return true for a empty string.

Comment: You want to check if `string` is `null` without typing `string == null`? That doesn't make sense, and trying to "trick" a tool is rarely a good idea. Either figure out why sonar is complaining and fix it, or tell it to quiet down.

Comment: you're checking is a string is null, why would you try using any other means to do that? only because some tool is restricting you? what is sonar's complaint exactly?

Comment: Step 1. uninstall sonarqube. Step 2. Use `strName == null`.

Comment: What is the rule which raises the issue on ``if(string==null)``? If it bothers you that much, you can disable this rule on your quality profile (uninstalling SQ looks like the nuclear option here) or just mark your issue as false positive.

Comment: Sonarqube didn't throw a violation for such usage. So its totally fine to use string==null?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Objects#isNull`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#isNull-java.lang.Object-) if you don't want to ignore or fix sonar.

Answer (score 0):

`StringUtils.isEmpty(string)` checks if `string == null`, so you are not really avoiding that test. If you need to know if a String is null, just check if `string == null`.

The only other (silly) way to test for null is to dereference the String (for example, via `string.length()`) and catch the `NullPointerExeption` when it's null.

`StringUtils.isEmpty(string)` is useful whenever your code treats null and empty Strings the same way (which is common).